# Remove desktop after killing explorer.exe

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

I have a machine where the default windows shell has been replaced with a custom program using gpedit.msc;
at the startup I see only the custom program on a black screen, that it's what I want;
sometimes it happens to start for some reasons explorer.exe;
when I try to terminate it using:

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
```

the desktop background is not removed and the applications windows are not able to be fullscreen even if the windows bar is no more there (the maximum height is screen's height - windows bar height)

Is it possibile to terminate explorer.exe and flush away everything to be like after a system restart (no desktop background and no windows bar space locked)?